# Probability that a linear map is non-singular over $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: probability, matrices, finite-fields, singularity

In his paper [Breaking Rainbow Takes a Weekend on a Laptop](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/214.pdf), the author claims the following:

> The probability of a random $o_2\times o_2$ matrix is singular over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is $$1-\prod_{i=0}^{o_2-1}\left(1-q^{i-o_2}\right).$$

Can someone help me derive this? The author says to use the following fact:

> A matrix is singular whenever the first row is non-zero, and for each consecutive row $i$, the $i+1$-th row is not in the span of the first $i$ rows.

He then says that this happens with probability $q^{i-1-o_2}$ but I don't see how this is true, or how it connects to the terms in the product, despite them looking somewhat similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the passage you've (mis)quoted actually says is:

> A matrix is $\color{red}{\text{non}}$-singular whenever the first row is non-zero, and for each and, for each $\ i < o_2\ $, the $\ i+1$-th row is not in the span of the first $\ i\ $ rows.

The probability that the matrix is *non*-singular is $\ \prod_\limits{i=0}^{o_2-1}\big(1-q^{i-o_2}\big)\ $, and therefore the probability that it's *singular* is $\ 1-\prod_\limits{i=0}^{o_2-1}\big(1-q^{i-o_2}\big)\ $.

You've also misread what it is that happens with probability $\ q^{i-1-o_2}\ $. This is the probability that the $\ i$-th row *is* in the span of the first $\ i-1\ $ rows.  This is because, given that the first $\ i-1\ $ rows are linearly independent, they span a space of dimension $\ i-1\ $, and all spaces of dimension $\ i-1\ $ over $\ \Bbb{F}_q\ $ contain exactly $\ q^{i-1}\ $ members.  The $\ i$-th row is equally likely (and therefore with probability $\ q^{-o_2}\ $) to be any member of $\ \Bbb{F}_q^{\,o_2}\ $, and hence the probability that it will lie in the span of the first $\ i-1\ $ rows is $\ \frac{q^{i-1}}{q^{o_2}}=q^{i-1-o_2}\ $. Therefore the probability that it is *not* in the span of the first $\ i-1\ $ rows is $\ 1-q^{i-1-o_2}\ $, and the probability that the matrix is *non*-singular is then the product of those quantities over $\ i\ $ from $\ 1\ $ to $\ o_2\ $.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see the confusion now.

Comment: Just a question, why is that the author got $\prod_{i=0}^{o_2} \left(1-q^{i-o_2}\right)$ instead of $\prod_{i=0}^ {o_2} \left(1-q^{i-1-o_2}\right)$? Is it a typo?

Comment: I made a mistake at the end of my answer.  In the argument, *my* $\ i\  $ starts at $\ i=1\ $ with the first row, and ends at $\ i=o_2\ $ with the last row. So I should have said (and, after correcting it, now do say) that the probability is the product of the quantities $\ 1-q^{i-1-o_2}\ $ over $\ i\ $ from $\ 1\ $ to $\ o_2\ $, and this is the same as the product of the quantities  $\ 1-q^{i-o_2}\ $ over $\ i\ $ from $\ 0\ $ to $\ o_2-1\ $, as given in your cited paper.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, thank you!